# How to find largest element

Tags: coq

I want to find the greatest/largest element among four lists of natural numbers. The elements are in sequence (from `1` to `n` in `list1`, `1` to `n-1` in `list2`, `1` to `n+4` in `list3`, `1` to `n-2` in `list4`) and I also have their lengths. I compared two lists to find the list with greater length, but I have a problem in comparing the result of first two lists with the third and fourth one.

```
Definition sort (l1 l2 : list nat) : nat :=
    if leb (length l1) (length l2) then 
      length l2
    else if leb (length l2) (length l1) then
      length l1
    else 0.
```

Please guide me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You have four lists `l1`, `l2`, `l3` and `l4` and want to get the longest list of the four?

Comment: Regarding what you already wrote by the way, the `else if` is unnecessary, if `|l1| ≤ |l2|` doesn't hold, then `|l2| ≤ |l1|` does. You don't need to test it.

Comment: I have 4 natlists.l1[1,2,3,4] l2[1,2,3] l3[1,2,3,4,5]l4[1,2].
I want to find greatest or equal element among four lists.
Like in first iteration it should be 5 , in second iteration 4 ,in third it should be 3 then 2 and  1. Starting from highest element then moving towards lowest one.

Comment: I have done this  l2| ≤ |l1|,because after this testing condition I get natural number which I want to use in testing condition for l2 and l3.

Comment: Isn't that always `n+4`?

Comment: Length of lists may vary,I calculated their length from length function.
I am just finding the greatest element among the lists and assign it to a variable. When recursive function call again it gives second  greatest number among list and so on .
Since elements are in ascending order, it means greatest element in each list is at the end  .Therefore we have to compare last elements of lists to find the bigger one.